# why does msgrcv() sets msqid to 0?

Tags: c, message-queue

I have a program in c which is supposed to send and receive ipc messages through msgq.

The problem I have is that when I run `msgrcv()` it sets my global `int msqid` to 0. And of course I need it at other methods, like in a signal handler.

here is some code:

```
/* all the includes and some variables*/
#include "msg.h" // include the one I made
int msgQ; // global int

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    key = ftok("progfile", 65);
    msgQ = msgget(key, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    printf("msg queue id: %d \n", msgQ);

    start_tik_tok(); // setting up the timer and the signal handler
    /* irrelevant code */

    void read_msgs(msgQ);
}

void read_msgs(int msgQid)
{
    while (1)
    {
        printf("before the read local:%d goval:%d\n", msgQid, msgQ);
        int ret = msgrcv(msgQid, &message, sizeof(message), 1, 0);
        printf("after the read local:%d global :%d\n", msgQid, msgQ);
        if (ret == -1)
            /* error handling */

        switch (message.action_type)
        {
            /* mesage handling */
        }
}

void signal_handler(int signo)
{
    /*I need the global int here to send some messages */
}

void start_tik_tok()
{
    //timer interval for setitimer function
    struct itimerval timer;
    timer.it_interval.tv_sec = 1; //every 1 seconds
    timer.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
    timer.it_value.tv_sec = 1; //start in 1 seconds
    timer.it_value.tv_usec = 0;

    //action for the signal
    struct sigaction new_sa;
    memset(&new_sa, 0, sizeof(new_sa));
    new_sa.sa_handler = &signal_handler;

    sigaction(SIGALRM, &new_sa, NULL);
    setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &timer, NULL);
}
```

the `msg.h` file:

```
#include <sys/msg.h>

struct msg_buff{
    long mesg_type; //reciver
    int sender; //sender
    char action_type;
    char time_tiks; //time in tiks
} message;
```

output:

> msg queue id: 45416448
>
> before the read local:45416448 global:45416448
>
> after the read local:45416448 global:0
>
> ...

you can see that after I run `msgrcv()`, the value of `msgQ` turns to 0, even though I'm using a variable to pass the value to the method `read_msgs()`.

Comment: Do not post questions with fake code that omits anything related to your problem. What is `message`? Where is it declared? What are you doing in all the code you've elided with comments?

Comment: okay, let me add it ;)

Comment: Maybe that name is already in use by the library and you should use something else, but that's unlikely. You said you were using `msgQ` in a signal handler too? Isn't the signal handler the one setting it to 0? Remember a signal will interrupt your code, if it's interrupted on the `msgrcv()` call then it is only expected that `msgQ` will change between one `printf()` and the other.

Comment: In an additional note, globals that are modified by a signal handler should be `volatile`.

Answer (score 1):

The `msgrcv` function takes a pointer to a structure that starts with a "header" of type `long`, followed by the message data. The third argument to `msgrcv`, `msgsz`, is the size of the message data body, **not including the `long` that's the header**. So you should pass something like `sizeof message - sizeof(long)`. By passing `sizeof message`, you're asking it to overflow the buffer `sizeof(long)` bytes, and this is clobbering some other global variable.

Comment: if I do that I get `error 7: Argument list too long`

Comment: @JavierFuentes `int ret = msgrcv(msgQid, &message, sizeof(message) - sizeof(long), 1, 0);`

Comment: yes, with the command `ipcs -q` i can see that each message is 16 bytes long, just like `sizeof(message)` retunr value. but If I do `sizeof(message) - sizeof(long)` I get 8, wich makes 'msgrcv' return with errno 7(Argument list too long)

Comment: @JavierFuentes: You probably have a corresponding error on the sending end.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I'm not sure why is that but it solved it.

I just initialized the int from the beginning.

changed:

```
int msgQ; // global int
```

for:

```
int msgQ = 0; // global int
```